socialaccount_socialapp_sites and sites_site data relations missing after allauth install
I am working on a web app in django and I'm trying to setup Oauth for google sign in. I have been gettin errors concerning migrations for socialaccount, the initial migration was missing so i manually created it. I solved one error but now I found out I am missing two tables in my database: socialaccount_socialapp_sites and sites_site. I am fairly new to django and programming in general so I would really appreciate some help. While installing allauth I had some issues (ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_path' from 'setuptools' ) so I had to downgrade setuptools and then upgrade them again in order for it to even install. Could that be the cause?

Faking migrations typically should be a last resort, I think there the problem originated.

Perhaps it is worth starting back from scratch: resetting the database to the point before the google sign in, then show what you did to fix these errors. Because with the current amount of information, it is (close to) impossible to tell what the problem is.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
